# How do i make the vue model reflect a change

Tags: vue.js

I have a very simple task i am trying to solve. I want to make the vue model update or display in a new property called chunk2 when there is a change. I am sending the value back to using this.chunk=this.chunk2. How can I achieve this. The result after the button is clicked should say "This is a chun"..in which the "k" gets removed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  chunk:"this is a chunk",
  chunk2:"",
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
    this.chunk.split('n')[1];
    alert(this.chunk.split('n')[1]);
    this.chunk=this.chunk2

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
{{chunk}}
{{chunk2}}
<br>
<button v-on:click="toggle()">magic

</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observations :**

- Strings are immutable. Hence, The string manipulation methods such as split returns a new array and will not update the original string. Ex **:**

```js
let chunk = 'this is a chunk';

const newStr = chunk.split('n');

console.log(chunk); // this is a chunk (Not changing the original string)

console.log(newStr); // updating the maniupulated values in a new variable.
```

- As `chunk2` is an empty string and you are assigning it back into `chunk` will update `chunk` also empty.
- `this.chunk.split('n')` will split the string with excluding `n`. Hence, If you want to include `n`. You have to split it with `k`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    chunk:"this is a chunk",
    chunk2:"",
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
      this.chunk = this.chunk.split('k')[0];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  {{chunk}}
  {{chunk2}}
  <br>
  <button v-on:click="toggle()">magic
  </button>
</div>
```